# Sharing TServerClientThread between threads in Delphi XE 6

Tags: multithreading, sockets, delphi

I'm programming in Delphi XE 6 using sockets (TServerSocket, TServerClientWinSocket and others from System.Win.ScktComp) the TCP server that receives messages from clients (actually it is HL7 messages) processes it and sends responses (acknowledgments). Processing includes an analyzing incoming messages and an executing SQL queries.

So I wrote a class TSocketThread that is a TServerClientThread descendant and it is instantiated at OnGetThread handler (it works in the blocking mode).

To avoid potential timeouts I break reading from the socket and processing the messages into two threads. So I added TProcessThread that represents a thread and queue of bytes protected with critical sections. When TSocketThread reads some bytes from the socket it puts them into TProcessThread's queue and TProcessThread then reads it, composes the HL7 message, processes and forms the response (the acknowledgment).

Now goes the main part of my question. I pass SocketThread: TServerClientThread, which I got from OnGetThread event handler, to both TSocketThread and TProcessThread. TSocketThread reads requests, TProcessThread writes responses.

So is this a legal way to share the SocketThread between two threads? And if it is not, what is the right solution for accessing the socket from two threads (one of them only reads and another one only writes)?

Comment: What you describe is perfectly fine, as long as you ensure that your worker threads do not outlive the server's thread that owns them. And it is perfectly safe to have separate reading and writing threads, as a socket has separate reading and writing buffers.

Comment: Ok, thanks @RemyLebeau!